# Prove that $a$ is a linear map and write the matrix in a given basis

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, linear-transformations, change-of-basis

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ and let $a:\,R_n[X]\to R_n[X]$ be the derivative linear map, such that $a(P)=P'$.

I am aware that it must satisfy the conditions of:

1. $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$
2. $f(kx)=kf(x)$

However I don't really understand how I should I apply this to it? Also, how can I write the resulting matrix of $a$ in the basis ($1$, $X$, $X^2$ , . . . , $X^n$).

Can someone run me through this example?

Comment: What is your $R_n$? I presume you are referring to formal derivatives?

Comment: When in doubt, fall back on definitions. For (1), $a(P+Q)=(P+Q)'$. Does this equal $a(P)+a(Q)=P'+Q'$ for all $P$ and $Q$? Remember, too, that the columns of the transformation’s matrix are the images of the basis vectors.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A = (a_{ij})$ be the matrix of $a$ in basis $(1, X, \dots, X^n)$.

Here is how to construct $A$:

$$\begin{array}{cc}
\begin{array}{cccc}
a(1) & a(X) & \dots & a(X^n)
\end{array} & \\
\left(\begin{array}{cccc}
a_{11} & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1p} \\
a_{21} & a_{22} & \dots & a_{2p} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\
a_{n1} & a_{n2} & \dots & a_{np}
\end{array}\right)&
\begin{array}{c}
1\\ X\\ \vdots \\X^n
\end{array}
\end{array}$$

So $a_{ij}$ is the coordinate of $a(X^{j-1})$ with respect to $X^{i-1}$.

After you've done all the computations, you should get
 $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & \dots & 0 \\  0 & 0 & \dots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \dots & n-1 \\ 0  & 0 & \dots & 0  \end{pmatrix}$$

Answer (score 0):

You know that the operation of taking derivatives satisfies 1) the sum rule, and 2) you can take out constants (you could think of this as a special case of the product rule, if you must). I don't see what it is you have to show here, the question seems ill-posed.

For your second question, amd's hint is a good one. Think about what matrix you have to premultiply the column vector $\begin{pmatrix} 1 \\ x \\ \vdots \\ x^n\end{pmatrix}$ to get each term sent to its derivative.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

The $k$-th column vector  of the matrix of $a$ are the coordinates of $a(X^k)=kX^{k-1}$ in the standard basis of $R_n[X]$.